# Am I supposed to see notifications for comments on deleted posts?

Tags: support, notifications, global-inbox, comment-replies, deleted-posts

I received a notification for a comment-reply addressed to me, but when I followed the [link to the post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/247790?noredirect=1), the post had been deleted.  At this point I figured I just had a stale view of the page, so I refreshed the page.  The comment notification was still in my inbox, and the link to the deleted post was still there.

[image: Inbox with notification for deleted comment]

If memory serves, refreshing the page would remove comment notifications for deleted posts.  If it's relevant, I first viewed the notification when my ios app alerted me of the comment.  Opening the notification lead to a page that said the question was deleted.  And opening the page in my browser mentions that it "was removed from Meta Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation."

This notification is also sticking around in my SE network inbox.  It stuck around even after syncing my oldest profile.

[image: SE Network inbox]

Is this the intended behavior of notifications?  Or am I just misremembering?

Comment: Is it supposed to persist even now?  In the past, refreshing the page also removed those notifications.

Comment: I might be wrong, searching past questions here about this brought conflicting data. Do you still have notification for my first (and now deleted) comment here?

Comment: @ShadowWizard no I don't have the notification for the first comment.  Just the most recent one.  But do comment replies on the same post collapse into only the most recent comment?

Comment: @ShadowWizard did the notification combine the comments for you here?

Comment: Yes indeed, it's showing only the latest comment in the top bar, however in the full inbox (via network profile) it's showing all of them: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jnzEz.png.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for that that image.  I'm going to add my SE inbox to the question.  It still shows stuff for me.