# Should not Inbox notifications on a deleted question be removed as well?

Tags: support, user-interface, global-inbox

Not sure this is the place to post this...
I notice that Inbox notifications (in my case, over a comment I left) on a question that was deleted - still show up - even though the question was ultimately deleted.

Should not these inbox notifications be deleted as well ?

Example: the inbox notification below refers to a question deleted weeks ago
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Am I supposed to see notifications for comments on deleted posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266422/am-i-supposed-to-see-notifications-for-comments-on-deleted-posts)

Comment: How much time was there between deletion and you checking your inbox? And are we talking about the inbox you access from the top bar or the "inbox" on your network profile

Comment: I find it interesting this question is being closed on the basis of the existence of a [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266422/am-i-supposed-to-see-notifications-for-comments-on-deleted-posts) already having being asked - with no answers whatsoever

Comment: On Meta sites that is an option. Is that question the same as this one?

Comment: @rene: yes. Does it answer it ? no

Comment: Can you post the link  to that comment from June 2nd here please? I want to verify something

Comment: @rene: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/119840283?noredirect=1) is the link to the comment to the deleted question I am referring to

Comment: Okay, this is by design. The comment still exists on the delete question so technically is not deleted but due to you not having > 10K you can't see deleted posts and therefor can't see the still existing comment.

Comment: Ok, thanks. By the way, I should [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266422/am-i-supposed-to-see-notifications-for-comments-on-deleted-posts) should be closed for the same reason (and indicate it has an answer elsewhere).

Comment: Here is the prove for completeness:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqRt8.png